# How to find a integer using modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

Hi guys, I'm preparing for my maths exam in 2 weeks and these sorts of questions come up every year. Unfortunately I was out when the lecturer taught us how to do these and I looked up his notes but they're not that good and they're really bad at explaining on how to do these sorts of questions.
Can anybody help me or give me hints/tips on how to approach/do these types of questions?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: The first one comes [from the Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/chinese.shtml) and the second one comes from [modular exponentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation).

Comment: For the second problem, use [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) which will get you $3^m\equiv 3^{m~\bmod~10}\pmod{11}$, so $x=3^2=9$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Find the least common multiple of $5$, $7$, and $9$. Let's say this is $n$. Then, try to find the unique integer $0 \leq r < n$ such that $x \equiv r \pmod n$. Any solution to that second equation is a solution to the original three. This comes from the Chinese Remainder Theorem and [a proof along with some examples can be found here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/chinese.shtml).

b) Express the exponent in binary and then break the $3^{20000052}$ up into a product of powers of $3$. Then, find the remainder of each power in the product using by squaring the previous one and then multiply all of the remainders together. This is really confusing to explain, but [makes more sense when you've seen a few examples](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation).

Since $11$ is prime, you can also use [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to say that $3^m \equiv 3^{m \mod 10} \pmod {11}$ so that $3^{20000052} \equiv 3^2 \pmod {11}$.

Comment: There's actually an easier way to solve the first problem without using CRT but involves a bit of grunt work. First, we solve the first two congruences by finding which one of $1,8,15,22,29$ is $\equiv 2\pmod5$. We note that $22$ works, so we have $x\equiv 22\pmod{35}$ as the solution to the first two congruences. Now, we solve this and the last congruence by finding which one of $22,57,92,127,162,197,232,267,302$ is $\equiv 4\pmod9$. We note that $22$ works, so our final solution is $x\equiv 22\pmod{315}$ which is the solution set to the problem.

Comment: To answer the first question, we can say x = 22 to get full marks wouldn't we. We don't need to say x is congruent to 22 (mod 315) since it doesn't ask for it, it only asks for an integer x

Comment: @MVantastic Yes, that's correct. It's just that any $x \equiv 22 \pmod {315}$ works, not just $22$, although that's the easiest solution.

Comment: Yes I understand that, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @learner A brute-force approach to this problem works, too, but I like the CRT better. $x=5t+2$, so $5t+2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, or $t \equiv 4 \pmod 7$, or $t=7s+4$, or $x=35s+22$. Thus, $35s+22 \equiv 4 \pmod 9$, or $s \equiv 0 \pmod 9$, or $s=9u$, or $x=315u+22$. Thus $x \equiv 22 \pmod {315}$ and we are done. Once you get used to knowing the small modular inverses very quickly, this method is a lot shorter than brute force, at least in my opinion.